Restart=always not working
I am struggling to make systemd restart a service when it crashes. This is the unit file:
# cat /etc/systemd/system/miscale.service
[Unit]
Description=Mi Scale Translator
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/root/miscale/miscale

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I often find the service down and when I check I see this:
# systemctl status miscale                                                                                                                          ● miscale.service - Mi Scale Translator
     Loaded: loaded (/root/miscale.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

How can the service be inactive (dead), I thought Restart=always should prevent that?
Edit: Here is the log (journalctl -u miscale) after such a failure:
Nov 12 23:04:34 raspberrypi miscale[847024]: [redacted] -28 181d [redacted]
Nov 12 23:04:36 raspberrypi miscale[847024]: [redacted] -34 181d [redacted]
Nov 12 23:04:38 raspberrypi miscale[847024]: [redacted] -29 181d [redacted]
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping Mi Scale Translator...
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi miscale[847024]: 2024/11/13 02:14:11 can't scan : context canceled
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: miscale.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: miscale.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped Mi Scale Translator.
Nov 13 02:14:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: miscale.service: Consumed 16min 12.743s CPU time.


If you just want it restarted by a crash then restart=on-failure might be better.   Do you know why the service is failing?   Systemd has defaults (which can be changed) on how many times it will attempt a restart and the interval between retart retrys.

Shouldn't always include on-failure? TBH I don't know which exit code the application is returning when it crashes, could very well be 0. The reason it crashes (this will only make sense if you know Go) is that I'm erroneously treating a canceled context as an error. I know how to fix this particular crash but it nicely exposes the restart issue I'm having, so for now I'm keeping the buggy version installed. It should crash every few days. If it got restarted it won't immediately crash again.

What do the logs from systemd look like when the service fails? Please post those as well. I suspect the service may simply be restarting too many times over an interval so that it gets disabled by systemd. See e.g. this answer for the solution in that case.

Always will include on-failure, but you specified it was  crashing and not restarting.  Aways can possibly restart it when you want  a normal shutdown.    Need to know more about how it is coming down.

@larsks If you mean the logs of the service (journalctl -u miscale), they are empty whenever I look. At that point the service has usually been dead for a couple of days or weeks. I don't know if systemd has any other logs.

I meant the logs from systemd itself (like Starting myservice or Dependency failed for myservice). Look at the output of journalctl -t systemd for logs related to your service.

If journalctl is empty because it failed a few days or weeks ago, then simply systemctl start miscale and see what it does.

@Stewart It starts normally. I never see it enter this "inactive (dead)" state, I also find it by chance.

@Stewart I have now added a log from a failure. Shouldn't I be seeing restarts in there?

Whenever I see this question, the answer is usually related to:

RestartSec= (default 100ms),
StartLimitIntervalSec= (default 10s), or
StartLimitBurst= (default 5 times)

If you start the unit (systemctl start miscale) and it fails immediately, systemd will wait RestartSec=, and then try again.  If it fails more than StartLimitBurst= times  within StartLimitIntervalSec=, then systemd will stop trying to restart it.
You can see that with the default values, a unit that fails immediately will hit the limit and will stop being restarted.
I often see this happen when a unit requires an online network, or an operational desktop environment, but is configured to start as soon as multi-user.target is online.  For those cases, I see two solutions:

Increase RestartSec= or StartLimitIntervalSec= to give that dependency (network, GUI) a chance to start-up.
Add appropriate dependencies such as After=network.target or using WantedBy=graphical-session.target instead of WantedBy=multi-user.target

Of course, this could also be an installation problem.  Maybe your service isn't calling the right binary, you're running with the wrong User=, there's a library or configuration file missing, or something else.  In those cases, tweaking RestartSec= isn't going to solve your problem.  It's best to look at journalctl -u miscale or even systemctl status miscale.
If miscale is a server, it may even be a matter of setting SO_REUSEADDR (if supported), so it can re-bind to the port.

This seems to be the best working theory so far. I was not aware that it only gets retried right away and if that fails then never again. (Raspberry Pi OS uses systemd 247, which doesn't have RestartSteps.) I cannot completely rule out that my program won't die again if it gets restarted 100 ms after it died. I have now set up a Telegraf/Grafana rule to alert me when it dies, maybe I get more information if I catch it in time.
